# Elasticsearch - Term aggregation of filtered fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm not entirely sure if this can be done but I'm trying to do a Term aggregation of filtered fields.

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.2 and my indexed documents look like the following.
Basically, every document belongs to a user and it contains, among other data, an array of comments that the user has made.

```
{
  "username": "John_162",
  "comments": [
    {
      "date": "2017-05-11",
      "type": "default",
      "content": "You guys need to check this site right now! www.randomsite.com"
    },
    {
      "date": "2017-05-19",
      "type": "default",
      "content": "This video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=111111) is very funny"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "username": "Elsa-Pat",
  "comments": [
    {
      "date": "2017-05-13",
      "type": "default",
      "content": "How are you guys doing today???"
    },
    {
      "date": "2017-05-14",
      "type": "default",
      "content": "My latest video is here: www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnnnn. Tell me what you think!!"
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to first analyse all the comments of all the users and look for the appearance of a certain pattern. In this case, I'm trying to look for URLs.
After that, I would try to do a Term aggregation of the URLs found.

The desired output in this case would be:

```
{
  "www.youtube.com": 2,
  "www.randomsite.com": 1
}
```

I'm able to _search for users that have a link in one or more of their comments, but I don't even know where to start in order to count them and group them as explained above.

Is this a feasible goal to do in a query, or should I be running a separate script that analyses the documents?